# Dataset to sqldatareader conversion

Tags: c#, dataset, sqldatareader

I've a dataset with a table and I want to copy these values to sqldatareader. Is there any way to do this in C#?

I tried with `ds.CreateDataReader();` but it is returning DataTableReader and not SQLDataReader.

Can someone tell me how to get it done?

Comment: Why do you need a `SQLDataReader`?  Can you use the `DbDataReader` class that both inherit from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't copy data to a data reader, because the data reader doesn't contain any data in itself, it reads from a data source.

Each data reader reads from a specific data source, so for an `SqlDataReader` the data source would be an SQL Server database, not a `DataSet` object.

So, what you are specifically asking for is not possible. If you can use the `DbDataReader` base class instead of specifically the `SqDataReader` class, then you can use any data reader.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. I think this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A `SQLDataReader` is for reading data from SQL Server, not from a `DataSet` - you'd have to get the original SQL query that was used to populate the dataset and re-query the server.